# Why must I manually edit the XML file in Eclipse? Can it be set to be done automatically as I develop the UI?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I do not have to do such manual updating in App Inventor so it is logical that Eclipse would have a similar automatic update feature.

Comment: and how do you "develop the UI" in Eclipse without writing code in XML?

Answer (score 0):

App Inventor is made especially for non-programmers. Its main purpose is to give everybody the possibility to basicly develop an app so that one with a great idea and no or low programming knowledge would be able to get it done.

Now, Eclipse is an IDE that integrates great with the Android SDK. So it only helps you with basic stuff that any IDE does, plus some things about Android integration (like test your app on the emulator/device really easy).